# Rank of the sum of an all-ones matrix and an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Let $B$ be an all-ones matrix of dimension $n \times n$, and $I$ be the identity matrix of dimension $n \times n$. Define $A = \frac{1}{n}B - I$. For $n=3$, $A$ would yield

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2/3 & 1/3  & 1/3  \\
1/3  & -2/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3  & 1/3 & -2/3
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

How would one compute rank$(A)$ for any $n$?

I have noted that any row $r_i$ of $A$ can be written as a linear combination of the other $n-1$ rows. Specifically, $r_i = - \sum_{j\neq i} r_j$. This implies rank$(A) < n$, but I don’t know how to compute the exact rank of $A$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply by $-3/2$ to obtain a matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal.

Answer (score 4):

Notice the matrix rank is subadditive. i.e. for any $n\times n$ matrix $P, Q$, we have

$${\rm rank}(P+Q) \le {\rm rank}(P) + {\rm rank}(Q)$$

Since ${\rm rank}(B) = 1$, we have

$$n = {\rm rank}(-I) = {\rm rank}\left(A - \frac{B}{n}\right) \le {\rm rank}(A) + {\rm rank}\left(-\frac{B}{n}\right) = {\rm rank}(A) + 1$$
This implies ${\rm rank}(A) \ge n - 1$. Together with the inequality
you have ${\rm rank}(A) < n$, you can deduce ${\rm rank}(A) = n -1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to compute $ker(A)$:

$ker(A)= span \{(1,1,1,...,1)^T\}$.

Hence $\dim ker(A)=1$ and so $rank(A)=n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are in characteristic zero. Then $B$ is symmetric over the reals and is diagonalisable.

The eigenvalues of $B$ are $n$ (with multiplicity one) and $0$
(with multiplicity $n-1$). Therefore the eigenvalues of
$rB+sI$ are $rn+s$ (with multiplicity one) and $s$
(with multiplicity $n-1$). When, say $rn+s=0$ and $s\ne0$, then $rB+sI$
has zero as an eigenvalue with multiplicity one, so its rank is $n-1$.